# find all events with ember-data in events api route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm very new in Ember world, and I'm struggling myself to make ember data work, but errors always happen.

I want get all my events with `this.findAll('events');` in my events route, i already setup everything right i think.. but still not working.

Currently two errors is appearing.

1:

```
WARNING: Encountered "data" in payload, but no model was found for model name "datum" (resolved model name using SiteApp.ApplicationSerializer.modelNameFromPayloadKey("data"))
```

2:

```
Error while processing route: events Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push' Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push'
```

I'm not getting where i'm messing up.

This is all i have:

Ember initialization.

```
window.SiteApp = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
```

Configuration of RestAdapter and RestSerializer:

```
SiteApp.ApplicationAdapter    = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
SiteApp.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

Events router:

```
SiteApp.EventsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.store.findAll('events');
  }
});
```

Events model:

```
SiteApp.Events = DS.Model.extend({
  _id         : DS.attr(),
  date        : DS.attr(),
  description : DS.attr(),
  hiw         : DS.attr(),
  hour        : DS.attr(),
  meeting     : DS.attr(),
  men         : DS.attr(),
  name        : DS.attr(),
  title       : DS.attr(),
  women       : DS.attr(),
  created_at  : DS.attr(),
  is_active   : DS.attr(),
  updated_at  : DS.attr()
});
```

So, when i access the route `/api/events`, this is the JSON format that i'm going receive:

```
{
  data: [{
    _id: "55f660bdd80a0fd2e298f333",
    title: "Pubx",
    date: "2015-09-05T03:00:00.000Z",
    created_at: "2015-09-14T05:53:01.292Z",
    __v: 0,
    updated_at: "2015-09-14T13:34:52.780Z"
  }, {
    _id: "55f660bdd80a0fd2e298f335",
    title: "Pub",
    date: "2015-09-05T03:00:00.000Z",
    created_at: "2015-09-14T05:53:01.610Z",
    __v: 0
  }, {
    _id: "55f660bdd80a0fd2e298f336",
    title: "Pub",
    date: "2015-09-05T03:00:00.000Z",
    created_at: "2015-09-14T05:53:01.769Z",
    __v: 0
  }, {
    _id: "55f660bdd80a0fd2e298f337",
    title: "Pub",
    date: "2015-09-05T03:00:00.000Z",
    created_at: "2015-09-14T05:53:01.943Z",
    __v: 0
  }, {
    _id: "55f6cc55f8aeb32de86a88e9",
    date: "2015-09-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    created_at: "2015-09-14T13:32:05.477Z",
    __v: 0
  }]
}
```

I already search a lot and i just cant figure out what is the problem here, i'm not seeing where is the problem.. :/

I'm using:

```
"ember": "~2.0.2",
"ember-data": "~2.0.1",
"jquery": "^1.11.3"
```

Thanks very much!

---

Update:

I change the json format to:

```
{
  data: [{
    _id: "55f660bdd80a0fd2e298f333",
    id: "55f660bdd80a0fd2e298f333",
    attributes: {
      date: "2015-09-05T03:00:00.000Z",
      description: "test",
      men: 50,
      women: 40,
      name: "name",
      title: "title",
      created_at: "2015-09-14T05:53:01.292Z",
      is_active: false
    },
    type: "event"
  }, {
    _id: "560e18bde4b0b27b28d5dd0d",
    id: "560e15b1e4b0b27b28d5dcf6",
    attributes: {
      date: "2015-09-05T03:00:00.000Z",
      description: "test",
      men: 50,
      women: 40,
      name: "name",
      title: "title",
      created_at: "2015-09-14T05:53:01.292Z",
      is_active: false
    },
    type: "event"
  }]
}
```

And i am still receiving the SAME error:

```
WARNING: Encountered "data" in payload, but no model was found for model name "datum" (resolved model name using SiteApp.ApplicationSerializer.modelNameFromPayloadKey("data"))

Error while processing route: events Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push' Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push'
```

I almost giving up :/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your payload needs to be modified to follow the [JSON API spec](http://jsonapi.org/). The data you are getting should be shaped like this:

```
data: [{
    id: "55f660bdd80a0fd2e298f333",
    type: "Event",
    attributes: {
        title: "Pubx",
        date: "2015-09-05T03:00:00.000Z",
        created_at: "2015-09-14T05:53:01.292Z",
        __v: 0,
        updated_at: "2015-09-14T13:34:52.780Z"
    }
},
```

If you don't have the ability to change how you receive the data, you have to reshape your JSON with your Serializer. See the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html) for more information.

Comment: I changed the JSON for this format but i'm still receiving the error, take a look: http://i.imgur.com/jUctuiM.png

Comment: should i change the Ember Model?

Comment: Hm, why the type is Event if the model is EventS??

Comment: I was able to achieve what i want, but i just setting the json array for 'event'.. can't i use 'data'?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that JSON format you are going to receive is not conventional. You could see expected payload for [RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html) or [JSONAPIAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html).

Solution depends on whether you can change your backend response. If you can, just make your response conventional. If you can't, you have to customize Adapter-Serializer pair to process payload properly.

Comment: How can i customize the Adapter? Is difficult?

Comment: I'd say not difficult and not easy :). Do you want to support read operations only or all CRUD?

Answer (score 0):

Warning clearly says no model found for model name 'data', if its possible you should change the back end response and use 'events' as the key for the JSON. Ember works on conventions. This is one of it. Else you need to change the model name from 'Events' to 'Data'. Also I see, I think you should change the model name to 'Event' instead of 'Events' similarly the backend response JSON.

If its not possible for you to change you have to JSON API as mentioned in one of the comments.

Comment: I can't change the name 'data' unfortunately. Can't i just send the data as the type "Events"?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using any adapter extending "DS.RESTAdapter". If so, you should extend "DS.JSONAPIAdapter".

That was the cause of my error.